# Angular service can't read Slim REST API link

Tags: angular, rest, slim

I have setup Slim REST API to get data from table `trading_partner`.

```
<?php
// Call database connection
require_once('dbconnect.php');

// Display all records
$app->get('/path/to/trading_partner', function($request) {

    $query = "SELECT *
              FROM trading_partner
              order by trading_partner_id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    if(isset($data)) {

        return json_encode($data);
    }

    mysql_close($conn);
});
```

Then I call it using this link.

```
http://localhost:52095/path/to/trading_partner
```

My problem is when I try to use the link in my Angular project, it doesn't output anything or it can't retrieve the data it provides. But when I try to literally copy the output of the link and paste it in a file and store it to the assets folder, by then Angular reads it correctly.

This is my `trading-partner.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { TradingPartner } from './trading-partner';

const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class TradingPartnerService {

  private tradingPartnerUrl = 'http://localhost:52095/path/to/trading_partner';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTradingPartners (): Observable<TradingPartner[]> {

return this.http.get<TradingPartner[]>(this.tradingPartnerUrl);
  }
}
```

and this is my trading-partners.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { TradingPartner } from './trading-partner';
import { TradingPartnerService } from './trading-partner.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-trading-partners',
  templateUrl: './trading-partners.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trading-partners.component.css']
})
export class TradingPartnersComponent implements OnInit {

tradingPartners: TradingPartner[];

constructor(private tradingPartnerService: TradingPartnerService) { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.getTradingPartners();
}

getTradingPartners(): void {
    this.tradingPartnerService.getTradingPartners()
    .subscribe(tradingPartners => this.tradingPartners = tradingPartners);
}

}
```

This is my trading-partner.ts class:

```
export class TradingPartner {
    trading_partner_id: number;
    tp_name: string;
    tp_location: string;
    flag: number;
    creation_date: string;
    created_by: string;
    update_date: string;
    updated_by: string;
}
```

I'm still learning Angular and PHP. What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I was running this using Chrome but when I tried to open my Angular app with Microsoft Edge, it shows the query table. I think this is browser support issue. Is there any way that Chrome can show the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally someone from my workmate helped me. It's an issue with the plugin in Chrome named,

Allow-Control-Allow-Origin

After installing and enabling it, I'm able to view the REST API call.